# Searching multiple database table with a single search parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables in a database now asking how can I search the four tables using a single search parameter with PHPMYSQL and display the result in a single page?
thanks alot friends.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please show some code that you have tried. Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? How are you displaying your results? What is your table structure, and which columns (column types) are you search?

Comment: can you give an example of the names of your tables, foreign key relationships etc?  sounds like you need a join, but more info needed on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select *
    From table1 inner join table2 on table1.col=table2.col 
    inner join table3 on table#.col=table3.col ..........
    where Col=?
```

you can replace on ?=? with "using (column)" if both tables have the same column name.